# Applying a function to a backreference within gsub in R

Tags: r, backreference

I'm new to R and am stuck with backreferencing that doesn't seem to work. In:

```
gsub("\\((\\d+)\\)", f("\\1"), string)
```

It correctly grabs the number in between parentheses but doesn't apply the (correctly defined, working otherwise) function f to replace the number --> it's actually the string "\1" that passes through to f.

Am I missing something or is it just that R does not handle this? If so, any idea how I could do something similar, i.e. applying a function "on the fly" to the (actually many) numbers that occur in between parentheses in the text I'm parsing?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Extract the numbers to a vector, apply the function on that vector, feed the result to `gsub`.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, extracting to a vector with gregexpr/regmatches is easy and I had been thinking about this -- but how do I feed this back to gsub?

Comment: @JMD welcome to stackoverflow.  When you post it is helpful to post minimal data set as well.  This link provides information on formatting questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 7, accepted):

R does not have the option of applying a function directly to a match via `gsub`. You'll actually have to extract the match, transform the value, then replace the value. This is relativaly easy with the `regmatches` function. For example

```
x<-"(990283)M (31)O (29)M (6360)M"

f<-function(x) {
    v<-as.numeric(substr(x,2,nchar(x)-1))
    paste0(v+5,".1")
}

m <- gregexpr("\\(\\d+\\)", x)
regmatches(x, m) <- lapply(regmatches(x, m), f)
x
# [1] "990288.1M 36.1O 34.1M 6365.1M"
```

Of course you can make `f` do whatever you like just make sure it's vector-friendly. Of course, you could wrap this in your own function

```
gsubf <- function(pattern, x, f) {
    m <- gregexpr(pattern, x)
    regmatches(x, m) <- lapply(regmatches(x, m), f)
    x   
}
gsubf("\\(\\d+\\)", x, f)
```

Note that in these examples we're not using a capture group, we're just grabbing the entire match. There are ways to extract the capture groups but they are a bit messier. If you wanted to provide an example where such an extraction is required, I might be able to come up with something fancier.

Comment: Works fine! Hadn't thought about `regmatches <-`. Thanks a lot. And sorry for the delay, but it took me some time to figure out that `ifelse()` was vector-friendly while `if() else` wasn't... R is cool but sometimes a bit too idiosyncratic indeed!

Comment: One way to use the capture group is use `pattern` in `f` to extract it for further use `v <- sub(pattern, "\\1", x)`.

Comment: Similar use case using capture groups: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49344399/2371031

Answer (score 2):

To use a callback within a regex-capable replacement function, you may use either `gsubfn` or `stringr` functions.

When choosing between them, note that `stringr` is based on ICU regex engine and with `gsubfn`, you may use either the default *TCL* (if the R installation has `tcltk` capability, else it is the default TRE) or PCRE (if you pass the `perl=TRUE` argument).

Also, note that `gsubfn` allows access to all capturing groups in the match object, while `str_replace_all` will only allow to manipulate the whole match only. Thus, for `str_replace_all`, the regex should look like `(?<=\()\d+(?=\))`, where 1+ digits are matched only when they are enclosed with `(` and `)` excluding them from the match.

With `stringr`, you may use `str_replace_all`:

```
library(stringr)  
string <- "(990283)M (31)O (29)M (6360)M"
## Callback function to increment found number:
f <- function(x) { as.integer(x) + 1 }
str_replace_all(string, "(?<=\\()\\d+(?=\\))", function(m) f(m))
## => [1] "(990284)M (32)O (30)M (6361)M"
```

With `gsubfn`, pass `perl=TRUE` and `backref=0` to be able to use lookarounds and just modify the whole match:

```
gsubfn("(?<=\\()\\d+(?=\\))", ~ f(m), string, perl=TRUE, backref=0)
## => [1] "(990284)M (32)O (30)M (6361)M"
```

If you have multiple groups in the pattern, remoe `backref=0` and enumerate the group value arguments in the callback function declaration:

```
gsubfn("(\\()(\\d+)(\\))", function(m,n,o) paste0(m,f(n),o), string, perl=TRUE)
        ^ 1 ^^  2 ^^ 3 ^           ^^^^^^^          ^^^^
```

Comment: `str_replace_all` does not appear to work any differently than `gsub` when using a function that references backreferences/capture groups.

Comment: @BrianD If you can't use a callable with `str_replace_all`, you are using some very old R/stringr version. See [**online R demo**](https://tio.run/##RY3hCoIwFIX/@xQXf92LFupAEgyfQHqBgSybMpgrrgZF9Oxro6A/h@/A4TvsvTVnVvzEdWPjZiaA5IvQ7iDFpimqg6AeUJR0AqyayLWoC@rTZIqj6e7GzVwdPgheoNa9cZueNceeQQnvKBxY36wa9aCs/X3lQd@1RymRpLxk2AUkSvO/cCGYQpD3Hw) proving `stringr::str_replace_all` works as explained in the answer. There is no way to access capturing groups in the callback, but I do not claim it does in the answer. **OP uses a reference to the whole mach** and `str_replace_all` does the job well.

Answer (score 0):

This is for multiple different replacements.

```
text="foo(200) (300)bar (400)foo (500)bar (600)foo (700)bar"

f=function(x)
{
  return(as.numeric(x[[1]])+5)
}
a=strsplit(text,"\\(\\K\\d+",perl=T)[[1]]

b=f(str_extract_all(text,perl("\\(\\K\\d+")))

paste0(paste0(a[-length(a)],b,collapse=""),a[length(a)])  #final output
#[1] "foo(205) (305)bar (405)foo (505)bar (605)foo (705)bar"
```

Comment: Thanks but no, what I'm trying to do is to replace numbers in the string directly through the function. And str_replace_all from stringr doesn't work either, probably because it's based on gsub etc.

Comment: Thanks again, but doesn't seem to work when there are multiple occurrences of \\d in the string, such as in: (990283)M (31)O (29)M (6360)M

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way by tweaking a bit `stringr::str_replace()`, in the replace argument, just use a lambda formula as the replace argument, and reference the captured group not by `""\\1"` but by `..1`, so your `gsub("\\((\\d+)\\)", f("\\1"), string)` will become `str_replace2(string, "\\((\\d+)\\)", ~f(..1))`, or just `str_replace2(string, "\\((\\d+)\\)", f)` in this simple case :

```r
str_replace2 <- function(string, pattern, replacement, type.convert = TRUE){
  if(inherits(replacement, "formula"))
    replacement <- rlang::as_function(replacement)
  if(is.function(replacement)){
    grps_mat <- stringr::str_match(string, pattern)[,-1, drop = FALSE]
    grps_list <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(grps_mat)), function(i) grps_mat[,i])
    if(type.convert) {
      grps_list <- type.convert(grps_list, as.is = TRUE) 
      replacement <- rlang::exec(replacement, !!! grps_list)
      replacement <- as.character(replacement)
    } else {
      replacement <- rlang::exec(replacement, !!! grps_list)
    }
  }
  stringr::str_replace(string, pattern, replacement)
}

str_replace2(
  "foo (4)",
  "\\((\\d+)\\)", 
  sqrt)
#> [1] "foo 2"

str_replace2(
  "foo (4) (5)",
  "\\((\\d+)\\) \\((\\d+)\\)", 
  ~ sprintf("(%s)", ..1 * ..2))
#> [1] "foo (20)"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>